# Can the statement “Having an unusually long lingual frenulum can cause speech defects later in life.” be backed up by any statistics?

Tags: health, development

I do mean *any* statistics -- some controlled experiments, sieving through surveys, anything. I'm constantly being told old wives' tales by friends and old doctors' tales by doctors. I'm not asking for well-done science here, just if anybody has investigated anything at all -- any data.   This sentence has been added so that this question isn't considered a duplicate of the other three with similar wording.

Comment: [Ankyloglossia](https://www.rdhmag.com/pathology/oral-pathology/article/16409317/evaluation-of-a-tonguetie-the-range-of-motion-of-the-tongue-should-be-assessed-in-all-patients) (simple to understand link) is a shortened/thickened lingual frenulum, also known as tongue-tie, which most definitely can affect newborns, and even adults. Although I don't know what the opposite is called (and have not heard of it), this is a medical question, and is being closed for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

We need to distingush between short and long lingual frenulum.

I think there mnay be confusion.

A short lingual frenulum means the tongue cannot be lifted enough for normal speech. Some people wanting their tongue pierced may call that "long" since it may seem to come come closer to the tip of the tongue.

A long lingual frenulum would mean the tongue can be lifted higher. I know of a person who can move the tip of his tongue back to touch the area of the uvula.

Comment: I'm grateful someone caught the error in this old question, so thank you!!! Unfortunately, I'm closing it despite an answer. I did delete the medical part of the answer. Any medical advice (or anecdote) **must** be supported by a reliable source. The OP did not mention a tongue deformity save a long frenulum. In spite of this odd reception, I hope you continue to participate here. Thanks, you did this Q&A site a favor today.